# Why am I not getting keyboard input events when in full screen mode?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-2.0

I am having some problems with the Silverlight full screen mode.

If I switch my application to full screen all the input from the keyboard is not handled. No textbox input, no key down / key up event and probably much more. Here is a sample application that demonstrates this:

**Xaml :**

```
<Canvas>

<TextBlock Text="Try some input:" Canvas.Top="10" Width="100"></TextBlock>

<TextBox x:Name="tboxInput" Width="100" Canvas.Top="30"></TextBox>

<Button x:Name="btnFullScreen" Content="Go Full Screen" Canvas.Top="60"></Button>

</Canvas>
```

**Code behind:**

```
public Page() 
{

InitializeComponent();

btnFullScreen.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(btnFullScreen_Click); 
}

void btnFullScreen_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{

Application.Current.Host.Content.IsFullScreen = !Application.Current.Host.Content.IsFullScreen; 
if (!Application.Current.Host.Content.IsFullScreen)

btnFullScreen.Content = "Go Full Screen"; 
else

btnFullScreen.Content = "Go Normal Screen"; 
}
```

It is simple to see that in full screen mode you can't write text in the textbox. Am I doing something wrong here? Is there another way to switch full screen so this will not happen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This link should help you out: http://silverlight.net/forums/p/11519/36798.aspx

**EDIT**

And this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189023(VS.95).aspx) gives you a more detailed reason:

> When a Silverlight plug-in is in full-screen mode, it disables most keyboard events. This limitation of keyboard input during full-screen mode is a security feature, and is intended to minimize the possibility of unintended information being entered by a user. In full-screen mode, the only input allowed is through the following keys.
>
> UP ARROW, DOWN ARROW, LEFT ARROW, RIGHT ARROW, SPACEBAR, TAB, PAGE UP, PAGE DOWN, HOME, END, ENTER